# Filter rows based on column name

Tags: r

I have a dataset and some of the columns start with "Ref". I want to select all the columns that with "Ref" and check a condition in those columns only. Unfortunately, as the data is generated in another step, I don't know how many columns will start with "Ref", just that it will. All the "Ref" columns contain numbers. The condition want I want to check if any of the numbers in the column are not equal to 3 or -1.

```
Ref_1 <- c(3,3,3,4,3,9)
Ref_2 <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,8,3)
Ref_3 <- c(3,-1,3,3,3,3)
v1 <- c(2,4,3,1,-1,2)
b1 <- c(2,4,3,1,-1,2)
c1 <- c(2,4,3,1,-1,2)
df <- data.frame(Ref_1,Ref_2, Ref_3, v1, v1, c1)
```

Using the dataset above, row 4 - 6 should be picked up by the condition as it fails. The data in v1, b1 and c1 should be excluded because it didn't start with "Ref".

I can use a if-else statement, but that will require me to hard code the "Ref" columns into the statement. How do I make it general enough so that it will pick out the rows that meet that condition without knowing all the "Ref" columns in the dataset?

Answer (score 4):

```
## with dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(starts_with("Ref")) %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), \(x) !x %in% c(3, -1)))
#   Ref_1 Ref_2 Ref_3
# 1     4    -1     3
# 2     3     8     3
# 3     9     3     3

## with base R
result = df[startsWith(names(df), "Ref")]
result[rowSums(sapply(result, \(x) !x %in% c(3, -1))) > 0, ]
#   Ref_1 Ref_2 Ref_3
# 4     4    -1     3
# 5     3     8     3
# 6     9     3     3
```

Comment: thank you for the assistance! I went with the dplyr solution because I already had the library loaded, but I appreciate the base R solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using *base*:

```
cols <- grep("^Ref", colnames(df), value = TRUE)
df[ which(rowSums(df[, cols] == length(cols) |
                  df[, cols] == -1) < length(cols)), cols ]
#   Ref_1 Ref_2 Ref_3
# 4     4    -1     3
# 5     3     8     3
# 6     9     3     3
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. Can you explain the purpose of "< 3"?

Comment: It should probably be `< length(cols)` instead of `< 3` since OP's main problem is adapting to variable number of "Ref" columns.

Comment: I'd also mention that the `*` in your regex pattern is bad, it's a "0 or more" quantifier being applied to the `f`, so this would match any column name starting with `"Re"`. You could change to `"^Ref"` without the `*` to fix. (`"^Ref.*"` might be what you're thinking, but the `.*` isn't necessary here.)

Comment: @user1845518 3 is the number of columns that start with Ref, I edited the post based on Gregor's helpful comments.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for comments, post is edited.